# TFS2012 WIX builds and relative paths

Tags: wix, wix3, heat

I'm setting up CI builds on TFS. A team member developers doesn't like idea of unloading the **.wixproj** file to edit the msbuild definition (because it is 'hidden') and I *kind of* agree with this.

So he has created a separate **setup.build** file which he calls with:

```
msbuild /t:Build;PublishWebsite;Harvest;WIX setup.build
```

The contents of which are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebSiteSource>..\InstoreApplications\</WebSiteSource>
    <SetupF>..\Setup\</SetupF>
    <PublishF>publish\</PublishF>
    <Publish>$(SetupF)$(PublishF)</Publish>
    <WebSiteContentCode>WebSiteContent.wxs</WebSiteContentCode>
    <WebSiteContentObject>WebSiteContent.wixobj</WebSiteContentObject>
    <!--<MsiOut>bin\\Release\\INT SMK Coles Store WebApi 1.0.1.msi</MsiOut>-->
    <MsiName>INT SMK Instore Applications 1.0.2.msi</MsiName>
    <MsiOut>bin\Release\$(MsiName)</MsiOut>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Defining group of temporary files which is the content of the web site. -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <WebSiteContent Include="$(WebSiteContentCode)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- The list of WIX input files -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixCode Include="Product.wxs" />
    <WixCode Include="$(WebSiteContentCode)" />
    <WixCode Include="WebAPIDlg.wxs" />
    <WixCode Include="IISConfiguration.wxs" />
    <WixCode Include="WixUI_InstallDirNoLicense.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- The list of WIX after candle files -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixObject Include="Product.wixobj" />
    <WixObject Include="$(WebSiteContentObject)" />
    <WixObject Include="WebAPIDlg.wixobj" />
    <WixObject Include="IISConfiguration.wixobj" />
    <WixObject Include="WixUI_InstallDirNoLicense.wixobj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Define default target with name 'Build' -->
  <Target Name="Build">
    <!-- Compile whole solution in release mode -->
    <MSBuild
        Projects="..\InstoreApplications.sln"
        Targets="ReBuild"
        Properties="Configuration=Release" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishWebsite">
    <!-- Remove complete publish folder in order to 
             be sure that evrything will be newly compiled -->
    <Message Text="Removing publish directory: $(SetupF)"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(SetupF)" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <Message Text="Start to publish website" Importance="high" />
    <MSBuild
        Projects="..\\InstoreApplications\InstoreApplications.csproj"
        Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
        Properties="Configuration=Release;WebProjectOutputDir=$(Publish)\;OutDir=$(Publish)bin\;" />
  </Target>
  <!-- Define creating installer in another target -->
  <Target Name="Harvest">
    <!-- Harvest all content of published result -->
    <Exec
        Command='"$(Wix)bin\heat" dir $(Publish) -dr INSTALLDIR -ke -srd -cg ApplicationComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out $(WebSiteContentCode)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="WIX">
    <!--     At last create an installer -->
    <Exec
        Command='"$(Wix)bin\candle" -ext WixIISExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixSqlExtension -dpublishDir=$(Publish) -dMyWebResourceDir=. @(WixCode, &apos; &apos;)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
    <Exec
        Command='"$(Wix)bin\light" -ext WixIISExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixSqlExtension -out "$(MsiOut)" @(WixObject, &apos; &apos;)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />

    <!-- A message at the end -->
    <Message Text="Install package has been created." />
  </Target>
  <!-- Optional target for deleting temporary files. Usually after build -->
  <Target Name="DeleteTmpFiles">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(Publish)" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(SetupF)" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <Delete Files="@(WixObject);@(WebSiteContent)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

This works absolutely fine on local machine.

For the TFS build I reference the setup.build file directly in the build defination and pass in the: "/t:Build;PublishWebsite;Harvest;WIX" in Advanced>MSBuild Arguments ...this produces a 'success' build however the build is no longer producing an MSI.

I ***believe*** the issue is between the HEAT generation of files and WIX picking these files up, note the variables:

```
<SetupF>..\Setup\</SetupF>
<PublishF>publish\</PublishF>
<Publish>$(SetupF)$(PublishF)</Publish>
```

The HEAT command **does** produce a folder with files on the build server, the folder ends up under /src rather than /bin and this is logically the same as building locally

However as the path is relative and I am guessing the WIX candle and/or light commands need their WorkingDirectory changed?...Is there a way to do this and not break the local build and not hardcode the path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a condition to let a property use a different value on a desktop build compared to TFS Team Build (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164288.aspx)).

If your script is run from within Visual Studio, check the BuildingInsideVisualStudio MSBuild property.

In TFS 20102, you usually customize your Build workflow to pass an MSBuild script workflow variables (e.g. [Pass Relative Path Arguments to MSBuild in TFS2010 Team Build](https://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/pass-relative-path-arguments-to-msbuild-in-tfs2010-team-build/)). In TFS 2013 is much easier as you have a lot of useful environment properties (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx)).